# How do you tell ASP .Net dynamic data to use stored procedures for select?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, select, dynamic-data

I see you can specify Insert, Update and Delete stored procs, but no straightforward way for SELECT stored procs.

Comment: are you using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: Does it have to be a SP, or can it be a View?

Comment: A view would be a cool work around, but wouldn't that still require me to give select permissions to the user?

Comment: Yes.  I think the same as if it were a table/SP.

Comment: how would a view be a work around for a stored procedure?  The two are completely different and are used for totally different requirements.  I think it might be better said that a VIEW is a better solution for this particular requirement, not a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable but not via the visual drag / drop tool.  You have to do three things:

1. Create a new method from the datacontext class that will be called to "get" your data

   ```
   public partial class DatabaseDataContext {
   [Function(Name = "dbo.Contact_Get")]
   [ResultType(typeof(Contact))]
   [ResultType(typeof(int))]
   public IMultipleResults GetContacts([Parameter(Name = "PageIndex", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> pageIndex, [Parameter(Name = "PageSize", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> pageSize, [Parameter(Name = "Sort", DbType = "NVarChar(10)")] string sort, [Parameter(Name = "ContactTypeId", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> contactTypeId) {
       IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), pageIndex, pageSize, sort, contactTypeId);
       return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create a new page template (List.aspx for example) for the particular table you want in the CustomPages folder to control the selecting from.
3. Control the gridview's selecting mechanism.

   ```
   protected void GridDataSource_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e) {
   DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext();
   IMultipleResults results = db.GetContacts(e.Arguments.StartRowIndex, e.Arguments.MaximumRows, e.Arguments.SortExpression, (int?)e.WhereParameters["ContactTypeId"]);
   e.Result = results.GetResult<Contact>().ToList();
   e.Arguments.TotalRowCount = results.GetResult<int>().Single<int>();
   ```

   }

Check out the Dynamic Data SP sample on the codeplex site for DD that shows you how to do this:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14473

Comment: this looks great. will look into it.

Comment: Can someone help update these instructions for entity framework?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for I believe is not *exactly* possible, because entities must be mapped to a table or a view of some sort.  A stored procedure is not something you can define an entity against.

However, it is certainly possible to create a mapping for a stored procedure that tells Linq2Sql to return entities when it's executed, and put a method in your DataContext class to run the sproc and get your list of entities.  These entities perform the same as entities created from a regular table mapping, so calling SubmitChanges() on them would use any Insert/Update/Delete sprocs that you had created for that entity type.

Probably the best thing to do would be to look at [this walkthrough by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

linq-to-sql is a very bad idea...

but this sproc should allow you to do what you want

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetCompanies] (
    @in_filter nvarchar(2000)
)
AS
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    begin
        set @sql = '
        SELECT 
            c.id as company_id, c.name as company_name
        FROM company c
        WHERE id is not null ' + @in_filter + ' order by c.type, c.name ' 
        exec sp_executesql @sql
    end
return
```

[sample](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Comment: I don't see how what you propose can be a solution.  I want to know where I would specify stored procs to be used for my SELECT statements

Comment: ok - i guess i didn't understand which part you needed. see the link in above answer

Comment: i'd like to stress that just because it is possible to use linq-to-sql, doesn't mean you should use it.  linq-to-sql is expressly forbidden in the environments i manage.