# How can I rapidly design ASP.Net webforms detail pages with many data fields?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I dread creating non-grid data detail screens in ASP.Net webforms. It's a painfully slow process for me compared to Windows Forms or WPF xaml screen layout. I know basic html concepts but my CSS skills are weak. **I'd like to learn how to rapidly crank out screens containing lots of data fields.** My company does not require fancy design.

My current project requires me to build numerous web pages, each displaying CRM type customer information. There are a TON of datafields to display for a single customer (in categories such as orders, invoices, price quotes, complaints etc). Initially, many of these screens will be a read-only web view of our legacy Vax system data.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Currently I lay out fields in HTML tables. **Are there any shortcuts, tips or tricks on how to speed up this process?** Any suggestions or recommendations are welcome.

Comment: Can you use asp.net mvc? Strongly typed view will outomatically generate editable field for you

Comment: The project is already in webforms. I started with MVC but my co-workers don't know MVC and don't have time to learn. They will help support the project.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at "Asp.net Dynamic Data"

> Dynamic Data supports scaffolding, which is a way to automatically
>   generate Web pages for each table in the database. Scaffolding lets
>   you create a functional Web site for viewing and editing data based on
>   the schema of the data. You can easily customize scaffolding elements
>   or create new ones to override the default behavior.

I must admit I haven't had a chance to experiment with it yet, but it might worthwhile taking a look at it as a possible tool for your developer-toolbelt.

I'm unsure how you'd be able to hook into a legacy system, but still might be worth a quick look at.

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework against SQL Server stored procedures (not SQL tables). The stored procedures access the Vax files with a Connx ODBC driver.

Comment: Cool, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059863/how-do-you-tell-asp-net-dynamic-data-to-use-stored-procedures-for-select